# Proving that 0 * x = 0 using only first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

I cannot prove that `0 * x = 0` using only first order logic and a minimum set of axioms (preferably from ZFC). Are there any axioms to look at on the world wide web?

Comment: I believe it's one of Peano's axioms that this equality holds.

Comment: The equation holds if $*$ denotes the multiplication in a ring where $0$ is the additive neutral element (and $x$ an arbitary element. So look up ring axioms.

Comment: What is the definition of $a*b$ you are using?

Comment: First order logic does not include any axioms for $0$. First order number theory might, but you'd have to tell us what axiom set you are using in first order logic.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen "First order logic" obviously includes a lot of things, but quite often "first order number theory" represents the natural numbers starting at $0$, and thus is not about a ring at all.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fair enough. Given any axioms assumed by ZFC.

Comment: ZFC does not include multiplication as a primitive symbol. You'd have to prove there exists a binary operation such that... So, again, from just the ZFC axioms, you are going to get a long proof. @JackWester

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The axioms I use for formal number theory in first-order logic come from Mendelson's "Introduction to Mathematical Logic." In the first edition that I have, the axioms are on page 103, and the theorem that you want is on page 104. In [this fourth edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZO1p4QGspoYC&pg=PT166&lpg=PT166&dq=number%20theory%20mendelson%20axioms&source=bl&ots=10swINesXE&sig=oGu4UkwMiao7hifr7YI8FSOT3wo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BkfqU_GzCIP-yQT3iYL4Dg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=number%20theory%20mendelson%20axioms&f=false) the axioms are on page 155 and the desired theorem on page 156. However, in both editions the theorem with some others " are left as exercises for the reader." Note that $x \cdot 0 = 0$ is an axiom, but not $0 \cdot x = 0$.

However, it is easy to prove by induction (covered in axiom S9). By axiom S7, it is provable that $0 \cdot 0 = 0$. By axiom S8, $0 \cdot (x') = (0 \cdot x) + 0$, which by axiom S5 equals $0 \cdot x$, which by the induction hypothesis is $0$.

Do you need more details?